# windows data grid showing extra blank column in right

Tags: wpf

my data grid is showing extra blank column in right how to avoid that.
below is my xaml code.

```
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Spool name" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding SpoolName}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Sheet num." Width="*" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="dgtxtBox" Text="{Binding SpoolName}" Margin="0,0,5,0"></TextBlock>
                                <Image x:Name="dgimgBox" Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ImagePathConverter}}" Height="12" Width="12"></Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="IsSeleted" Binding="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="0" Visibility="Hidden" IsReadOnly="True"/>-->
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

where you define your data grid specify AutoGenerateColumns to false so only the bindings are the columns shown so;

Datagrid AutoGenerateColumns="False

that should do the trick. same with rows if you ever encounter the problem (CanUserAddRows=false)

Comment: i did that still issue persist.

Comment: i cant see where you define your datagrid, can you include that, then can have a look from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to say is the extra blank that appears after all columns are shown. By default all columns have a witdh depending on the content within it. 
So if your datagrid is wither than that, you get an extra blank space.

One common way of get rid of that is to make the columns as wide as they can get.

```
<Datagrid ColumnWidth="*">
```

You have to be aware that the Datagrid Width **is not** the sum of all columns widths.

I hope is what you are looking for. Cheers